# How to create an ROI from an byte array

Tags: java, imagej

I'm stuck in my program, because I don't know how to "convert" my 3-Dim Array to an ROI.

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    for(j=0; j<512;j++){
        for(k=0;k<512;k++){
            if(ip.get(i,j) > threshold && mask[i][j][k]==0){
                mask[i][j][k]=4;}
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: I think this is mis-tagged, `matplotlib` is a python library.

Comment: I don't think that your question is well-founded, since ImageJ only has support for 2D ROIs.  Do you want to create an array of ROIs, one per slice? Going by your code sample, it looks as if you might want to look at the ThresholdToSelection plugin (`ij.plugin.filter.ThresholdToSelection`)